# Populating Google Map Markers from Node Mongodb model

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, google-maps-markers

I need some help to populate google map markers by using data on my Mongodb with NodeJS.

This is my Model Schema (models/listing.js):

```
var restful = require('node-restful');
var mongoose = restful.mongoose;

// Schema
var listingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  category: String,
  title:    String,
  location: String,
  latitude: Number,
  longitude: Number,
  url: String,
  type: String,
  type_icon: String
},
  { collection: 'listing' }
);

// Return Model
module.exports = restful.model('Listing', listingSchema);
```

When I use postman to GET /api/listing, this is what I have

```
[{
"_id": "57092ca64f43442f0bcd6a95",
"category": "services",
"title": "Musa 24 hours Printing",
"location": "16 Bali Lane, Singapore 189852",
"latitude": 1.3007598,
"longitude": 103.8588499,
"url": "http://www.musa-group.com/24hrsinternet/printing.html",
"type": "Printing",
"type_icon": "assets/icons/media/text.png",
"gallery": [
  "http://i.imgur.com/HwiyMCK.png"
]},
  {
    "_id": "57092ca64f43442f0bcd6a96",
    "category": "services",
    "title": "Rocket Printers SG",
    "location": "146 Jalan Bukit Merah, Singapore 160146",
    "latitude": 1.2778769,
    "longitude": 103.8308443,
    "url": "http://www.rocketprinters-sg.com/",
    "type": "Printing",
    "type_icon": "assets/icons/media/text.png",
    "gallery": [
      "http://i.imgur.com/XPYgZ7a.jpg"
    ]
  }]
```

On my index.ejs file, the markers are currently pulled from an items.json.txt file

```
<script>
var _latitude = 1.36080344;
var _longitude = 103.81565094;
var jsonPath = 'assets/json/items.json.txt';
    // Load JSON data and create Google Maps
    $.getJSON(jsonPath)
        .done(function(json) {
            createHomepageGoogleMap(_latitude,_longitude,json);
        })
        .fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    // Set if language is RTL and load Owl Carousel
    $(window).load(function(){
        var rtl = false; // Use RTL
        initializeOwl(rtl);
    });
    autoComplete();
</script>
```

How can I change the source from 'items.json.txt' to my 'Listing' database collection? Much appreciation for any help at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your JSON files has the same structure as the JSON returned by /api/listing, you can simply replace the URL of your JSON file by **yourserver.com:XX/api/listing**, assuming the server **yourserver.com** is running your API on port **XX**.

I suspect the [jQuery.getJson](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) method is just a wrapper around [jQuery.get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) that adds parameters to the request such as an appropriate `Content-Type` header.